# Deeplearning4j: unable to get linear index >= 1

Tags: java, java-8, deeplearning4j

I'm trying to train a neural network using deeplearning4j. But I get this error message which I cannot explain:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to get linear index >= 1
    at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.getDouble(BaseNDArray.java:3275)
    at org.deeplearning4j.eval.Evaluation.eval(Evaluation.java:197)
    at mypackage.myclass.main(Learn.java:77)
```

My data is in a csv file, it's 64 numbers (values 0,1,2,3) and a label of value -1000 to 1000 (floats).

for example:

```
 2,3,2,2,1,1,2,3,0,1,1,2,3,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,3,1,0,1,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3, 2,2,2,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,3,0,0,2,3,2,3,2,0,0,3,0,1,1,3,3,2,-228.0
```

I use this code to load the csv file and train the network:

```
RecordReader recordReader = new CSVRecordReader(0, ",");
recordReader.initialize(new FileSplit(new File("data.csv")));

DataSetIterator iterator = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader, new DoubleWritableCo    nverter(), 600000, 64, 64, true);

     DataSet allData = iterator.next();
     SplitTestAndTrain testAndTrain = allData.splitTestAndTrain(0.9);

     DataSet trainingData = testAndTrain.getTrain();
     DataSet testData = testAndTrain.getTest();

     //We need to normalize our data. We'll use NormalizeStandardize (which gives us mean 0, unit     variance):
     DataNormalization normalizer = new NormalizerStandardize();
     normalizer.fit(trainingData);           //Collect the statistics (mean/stdev) from the traini    ng data. This does not modify the input data
     normalizer.transform(trainingData);     //Apply normalization to the training data
     normalizer.transform(testData);         //Apply normalization to the test data. This is using     statistics calculated from the *training* set
     long seed = 123;
     int inputNum = 64;
     int hiddenNum = 64;
     int outputNum = 1;
     int iterations = 1;

     MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
         .seed(seed)
         .activation("tanh")
         .iterations(iterations)
         .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
         .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT)
         .learningRate(0.1)
         .regularization(true).l2(1e-4)
         .list()
         .layer(0, new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn(inputNum).nOut(hiddenNum).build())
         .layer(1, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MSE)
             .activation("identity")
             .nIn(hiddenNum).nOut(outputNum).build())
         .backprop(true).pretrain(false)
         .build();
     MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
     model.init();
     model.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(100));

     model.fit(trainingData); 

     //evaluate the model on the test set
     Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(2);
     INDArray output = model.output(testData.getFeatureMatrix());
     eval.eval(testData.getLabels(), output); <---- this is line 77, where the error occurs
     System.out.println(eval.stats());
     recordReader.close();
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the code for `BaseNDArray`?

Comment: @bradimus, the code is here: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/blob/nd4j-0.5.0/nd4j-backends/nd4j-api-parent/nd4j-api/src/main/java/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/BaseNDArray.java#L3275

Comment: It seems like it's because the number of output nodes is smaller than the possible labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying 2 labels for the evaluation. and then using eval on a regression problem.

Eval is mainly meant for classification. You'll have to hand roll your own regression evaluation.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So in my example I have some features with label -221, ideally the network would just output that number?